# android howto create an (incoming phone call) but not for talking

Tags: android

hi again
search around but cant find a way to start developing this
Wanted to send an image to my phone (ftp) and when the image has
arrived and saved to my CD card i would like to have the phone ringing like
it was someone calling. When i answer the image will fill the screen.

What i have done so fare is is that the image is received and saved to CD card.
Only the Phone call thing missing 
If you can give me a hint about what I need to do im happy
I know I can start a phone call activity with this code

```
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Maybe it can be modified to create a dummy call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `RingtoneManager` to acquire a `Ringtone` object and then `play()` it.

Comment: thanks. Think i must create my own activity that looks like a incoming phone call.